# Creating a dynamic Group By

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

```
df = data.frame(
  A = c(1, 4, 5, 13, 2),
  B = c("Group 1", "Group 3", "Group 2", "Group 1", "Group 2"),
  C = c("Group 3", "Group 2", "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")
)

df %>%
  group_by(B) %>%
  summarise(val = mean(A))

df %>%
  group_by(C) %>%
  summarise(val = mean(A))
```

Instead of writing a new chunck of code for each unique set of `group_by` I would like to create a loop that would iterate through the `df` data frame and save the results into a list or a data frame.

I would like to see how the average value of feature **A** is spread acorss features **B** and **C**, without having to write a new chunck of code for each categorical feature in the data set.

I tried this:

```
List_Of_Groups <- map_df(df, function(i) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!!syms(names(df)[1:i])) %>% 
    summarize(newValue = mean(A))
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `purrr`'s `map`, you can apply the chunk of code you specified to all the columns that are character. Basically you *map* the names of character variables to the function that follows

```
purrr::map(names(df %>% select(where(is.character))), function(i) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(i)) %>% 
    summarize(newValue = mean(A))
})
```

Output

```
# [[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   B       newValue
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 Group 1      7  
# 2 Group 2      3.5
# 3 Group 3      4  
# 
# [[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   C       newValue
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 Group 1      5  
# 2 Group 2      8.5
# 3 Group 3      1.5
```

Comment: pardon the pun but where is `where` from? package?

Comment: Thank you Ric, however I get this error:

Error: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.
i Contact the package author and suggest using `eval_select()`. 

Do you perhaps know why this error might occure? I tried installing the tidyselect package, but still the issue persists.

Comment: `where` is a `tidyselect` function that can be used in some `dplyr` statements as of `dplyr` version 1.0.0. You can look at some examples [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html)

Comment: @Loncar which version do you have of `purrr` and `dplyr`?

Comment: dplyr_0.8.5 and purrr 0.3.4 I will reinstall them and see if it helps :)

Comment: @Loncar It is better to update them :) otherwise you can use `names(df %>% select_if(is.character))` and the result will be the same

Comment: @RicS I installed the newest version for both dplyr, purrr and tidyselect, but for some reason the where function is not located within the tidyselect package. Eventhough I have the newest version (1.1.0) 

I tried your code and the version names(df %>% select_if(is.character)), but in both cases I get an empty list. Can't wrap my head around it, why do I get an empty list as a result

Comment: Are your variables character or factor? Have you tried whether it works if you write `c("B", "C")` instead of `names(...)`?

Comment: @RicS I tried with c("B", "C") and it worked. For some reason when it is a vector it works, but otherwise it does not. Do you know the reasoning behind this strange behaviour? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: It is very strange because `names()` should return a character vector of column names.. What is the output if you run `names(df %>% select(where(is.character)))` or `names(df %>% select_if(is.character))`?

Comment: In both cases an empty list. In the console result only this appears: list()
Which would be an empty list. It evalueates the code, but the output is just an empty list, while with c("B", "C") it works well. Interesting behaviour and yes, both variables are factors. 

You were right, I changed the data type into a character type for both features and now the initial code works. Thanks for the tip and everything! :)

Comment: Thank you for these details, I managed to understand what the (silly) problem is. I wrote `is.character` because as of R 4.0.0 the default `stringsAsFactors` argument is set to `FALSE`, so when I created the toy `df` the variables B and C are character, not factor. If you specify `names(df %>% select(where(is.factor)))` you should obtain some concrete results and not an empty list. Just be sure that all the variables you are interested in are indeed factors.

Comment: ah typical R problem, factors. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot it long, using A as an identifier, and then group by:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(-A) %>% group_by(name,value) %>% summarize(val=mean(A))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   name [2]
  name  value     val
  <chr> <fct>   <dbl>
1 B     Group 1   7  
2 B     Group 2   3.5
3 B     Group 3   4  
4 C     Group 1   5  
5 C     Group 2   8.5
6 C     Group 3   1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
empty_list <- list(0)
for(i in 2:dim(df)[2])
{
  empty_list[[i-1]]<-df %>% group_by(df[,i]) %>% summarise(val = mean(A))
}
empty_list

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  `df[, i]`   val
  <fct>           <dbl>
1 Group 1           7  
2 Group 2           3.5
3 Group 3           4  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  `df[, i]`   val
  <fct>           <dbl>
1 Group 1           5  
2 Group 2           8.5
3 Group 3           1.5
```

Hope this can help.