# R pass vector of grouping vars to purrr::map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Here is code that reads in a remote data set and prepares four summary tables showing counts for each category within the demographic variables of gender, education, ethnicity/race, and geographic region:

```
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(tidyverse)))

urlRemote_path  <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/"
github_path <- "DSHerzberg/WEIGHTING-DATA/master/INPUT-FILES/"
fileName_path   <- "data-input-sim.csv"

census_match_input <- suppressMessages(read_csv(url(
  str_c(urlRemote_path, github_path, fileName_path)
)))

var_order_census_match  <- c("gender", "educ", "ethnic", "region")

census_match_cat_count_gender <- census_match_input %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarize(n_census = n()) %>%
  rename(demo_cat = gender) %>%
  mutate(demo_var = "gender") %>%
  relocate(demo_var, .before = demo_cat)

census_match_cat_count_educ <- census_match_input %>%
  group_by(educ) %>%
  summarize(n_census = n()) %>%
  rename(demo_cat = educ) %>%
  mutate(demo_var = "educ") %>%
  relocate(demo_var, .before = demo_cat)

census_match_cat_count_ethnic <- census_match_input %>%
  group_by(ethnic) %>%
  summarize(n_census = n()) %>%
  rename(demo_cat = ethnic) %>%
  mutate(demo_var = "ethnic") %>%
  relocate(demo_var, .before = demo_cat)

census_match_cat_count_region <- census_match_input %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarize(n_census = n()) %>%
  rename(demo_cat = region) %>%
  mutate(demo_var = "region") %>%
  relocate(demo_var, .before = demo_cat)
```

I want to consolidate this code using `purrr::map()`. My thought was to iterate over the vector of variable names, as in:

```
census_match_cat_count <- var_order_census_match %>% 
  map(~
        census_match_input %>%
        group_by(!!.x) %>%
        summarize(n_census = n()))
```

This does not return the desired output; rather, it returns tables that lack separate rows and counts for the categories under each demographic variable.

Furthermore, when I try to expand the mapping function to include the rest of the code, as in:

```
census_match_cat_count <- var_order_census_match %>%
  map(
    ~
      census_match_input %>%
      group_by(!!.x) %>%
      summarize(n_census = n()) %>%
      rename(demo_cat = !!.x) %>%
      mutate(demo_var = .x) %>%
      relocate(demo_var, .before = demo_cat)
  )
```

I get back errors suggesting that I'm not using the correct `tidyeval` procedures.

There are related topics in Stack Overflow, but none seem to address my particular question of how to pass variable names to be used by `dplyr::group_by()` within `purrr::map()`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471927/creating-a-dynamic-group-by/62472387?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this without non-standard evaluation keeping column names as character.

```
library(dplyr)

var_order_census_match  <- c("gender", "educ", "ethnic", "region")

purrr::map(var_order_census_match, 
         ~census_match_input %>%
              group_by_at(.x) %>%
              summarise(n = n()) %>%
              rename(demo_cat = .x) %>%
              mutate(demo_var = .x) %>%
              relocate(demo_var))


#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  demo_var demo_cat     n
#  <chr>    <chr>    <int>
#1 gender   female     524
#2 gender   male       476

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  demo_var demo_cat         n
#  <chr>    <chr>        <int>
#1 educ     BA_plus        311
#2 educ     HS_grad        247
#3 educ     no_HS          133
#4 educ     some_college   309
#....
```

Comment: Thank you - I chose your solution because it's closest to my original code, and because it gave me the opportunity to learn about the SE version of `group_by()`. Also, I used `map_df()` which gave me the desired output in a single data frame.

Comment: Update: `group_by_at()` is now superceded in `dplyr` 1.0.0. I tested `group_by(across(.x))` in this solution, and it works and produces identical output.

Answer (score 0):

You could reshape the dataset using `pivot_longer` then `count`

```
library(tidyverse)
census_match_input %>% 
    pivot_longer(all_of(var_order_census_match), "demo_var", values_to = "demo_cat") %>%
    count(demo_var, demo_cat)

    # A tibble: 15 x 3
       demo_var demo_cat         n
       <chr>    <chr>        <int>
     1 educ     BA_plus        311
     2 educ     HS_grad        247
     3 educ     no_HS          133
     4 educ     some_college   309
     5 ethnic   asian           48
     6 ethnic   black          146
     7 ethnic   hispanic       252
     8 ethnic   other           64
     9 ethnic   white          490
    10 gender   female         524
    11 gender   male           476
    12 region   midwest        218
    13 region   northeast      173
    14 region   south          367
    15 region   west           242
```

Comment: Thank you - I see there's more than one way to solve this.